# Android auto - Google play rejection for Dark mode - How to fix?

Tags: android, google-play, android-theme, android-auto

My app was rejected because of Android auto. They say there was a problem with Dark mode. Check the message below.

I checked everything but couldn't find how to fix the problem. The app just provides Audio items to Android Auto app. Android auto app takes care for rendering the items. They have the same layout for every app.

**Do you have any suggestions what I am doing wrong?** Android Auto support was not built from me so maybe I don't understand where layouts or themes are located.

> Hi Developers at {company},
>
> Thanks for submitting your app for Android Auto.
>   We reviewed your app, {app_name}, with package name {pacage_name}, and noticed some eligibility issues. App status: Your app  has not been accepted into Android Auto, and the update is not live on Google Play.
>
> Eligibility issues by APK version: Version(s)Eligibility IssueAPK:307 No night mode Your app does not support both day mode and night mode (by rendering light text and controls on a dark background).APK:307App does not perform as expected
>   Your app does not perform all functions properly or as expected from a user perspective.
>
> To be considered for Android Auto:
>
> Make the necessary changes to your app.
>
> - Increment the version number of the upgraded APK.
> - Submit your app for another review.
>
> Or, if you’d like to exclude your app from Android Auto:
>
> - Remove the Android Auto manifest entry from your APK code.
> - Sign in to your Play Console and upload the new APK.
> - Click Submit update.
>
> For more details on how an app can qualify for Android Auto, you can review the Android Auto App Quality Guidelines.
>   If you feel we have made this determination in error, please submit additional information to our team and we’ll review your app again.
>   Thanks for supporting Google Play,
>   The Google Play Team

**Update 10.12.2018:**

Resubmitting the app for review helped. I could not find out why the app was rejected the first time. The layouts and images are not provided from my app so problem with dark/light mode doesn't sound like possible reason.

Comment: We can't give you any more details aside from what it already says: `Your app does not support both day mode and night mode (by rendering light text and controls on a dark background)`.

Comment: This sounds like reasonable explanation. I checked the implementation and my app provides list of audio items (title, url, etc) through a service. My app does NOT control the layout. I followed "Test apps for Auto" and my app shows the audio items the same way as "Play Music" for dark and light mode.
I really cannot understand what is the real problem. Every advice is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re correct that Android Auto takes care of rendering views to the screen. Developers using the Public SDK for media or messaging don’t have access to draw custom elements on the screen or manipulate the themes.

Here’s the description for [Day and Night transitions](https://developer.android.com/design/auto/#daynighttransitions) for the Auto app Design Quality documentation:

> All the UIs support different color schemes for day and night. The
>   platform provides the state (day or night) and makes adjustments
>   automatically.

The email you received also reads a little bit like they’re reviewing it as a full screen app using the complete SDK, instead of the Public SDK. I’d try to kick off another review by submitting the app again or try to get in touch with the Play Console support team